# Get data from one Excel and write to another Excel using the same format in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read two Excel files using pandas in python. Get data from one then write the data to another under a condition. Let's call the files *sourcefile1.xlsx* and *sourcefile2.xlsx*.

Here are the contents of the Excel files:

1. **sourcefile1.xlsx**
   Pair and Field Results are main headers that are merged.
   cable_type, cable_name, cable_pair, caller_id, result are secondary header that represents each column.

   ```
   -----------------Pair---------------   -----Field Result-----
   cable_type   cable_name   cable_pair   caller_id   result
   primary      2            103          n/a         not match
   primary      1            33           22222222    match
   primary      5            342          22222222    match 
   secondary    2            12           n/a         not match
   secondary    4            144          44444444    match
   ```
2. **sourcefile2.xlsx**

   ```
   -blank-     -----Secondary Pairs----    ------Primary Pairs------
   caller_id   caller_id  adsl  result       caller_id   adsl   result
   11111111               4/144                          2/103  
   22222222               2/12                           4/144 
   44444444               7/55                           4/144
   NULL                   8/123                          1/11
   NULL                   NULL                           2/22
   ```

The expected output will write on **sourcefile2** based on this pseudo code:

```
if caller_id(sourcefile1) != 'N/A':
    if cable_type(sourcefile1) = 'primary':
        if caller_id(sourcefile1) = caller_id(sourcefile2) - primary pairs:
            write caller_id(sourcefile1) to caller_id(sourcefile2) - primary pairs
            write result(sourcefile1) to result(sourcefile2) - primary pairs

elif caller_id(sourcefile1) != 'N/A':
    if cable_type(sourcefile1) = 'secondary':
        if caller_id(sourcefile1) = caller_id(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs:
            write caller_id(sourcefile1) to caller_id(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs
            write result(sourcefile1) to result(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs

elif caller_id(sourcefile1) = 'N/A':
    if cable_type(sourcefile1) = 'primary':
        if cable_name + cable_pair(sourcefile1) = adsl(sourcefile2) - primary pairs:
            write caller_id(sourcefile1) to caller_id(sourcefile2) - primary pairs
            write result(sourcefile1) to result(sourcefile2) - primary pairs

elif caller(sourcefile1) = 'N/A':
    if cable_type(sourcefile1) = 'secondary':
        if cable_name + cable_pair(sourcefile1) = adsl(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs:
            write caller_id(sourcefile1) to caller_id(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs
            write result(sourcefile1) to result(sourcefile2) - secondary pairs
```

Here is the output I am trying to attain.

```
-blank-     -----Secondary Pairs----    ------Primary Pairs------
caller_id   caller_id  adsl   result       caller_id   adsl   result
11111111               4/144              n/a         2/103  not match
22222222    n/a        2/12   not match    22222222    4/144  match
44444444    44444444   7/55   match                    4/144
NULL                   8/123                          1/11
NULL                   NULL                           2/22
```

I am trying to match the caller_id from **sourcefile1** to **sourcefile2** and write them to **Primary Pairs** or **Secondary Pairs** based from their **cable_type**. If the **caller_id** is **n/a**, then what I need to match is the **adsl**. The **result** is a given data, I will just need to get whatever is in the same row with the **caller_id** or **adsl**.

So far I was able to match the *caller_id* but I recreated the *sourcefile1* and *sourcefile2* and remove the main header. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('sourcefile2.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('sourcefile1.xlsx', 'v0.02')

forPrimary1 = df1.columns[40]
forSecondary1 = df1.columns[23]
ComparisonResult = df2.columns[22]

forAdsl = df1.columns[39]
CallerID = df2.columns[13]
forPrimary = df1.columns[37]
forSecondary = df1.columns[16]

df3 = pd.read_excel('PrimarySecondary.xlsx')
df4 = pd.read_excel('adslFile.xlsx')
df5 = pd.read_excel('PrimarySecondary2.xlsx')

# df1['svc_no'] = df1['svc_no']
df2['Adsl'] = df2[['cable_name', 'pair']].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
newPrim = df2[[caller_id, 'result', 'Adsl']] [(df2['cable_type'] == 'Primary')]
newSec = df2[[caller_id, 'result']] [(df2['cable_type'] == 'Secondary')]
newPrim.to_excel('newPrimary.xlsx')
newSec.to_excel('newSecondary.xlsx')

frame = pd.read_excel('newPrimary.xlsx')
frame1 = pd.read_excel('newSecondary.xlsx')

df1['b_line_stat'] = df1['b_line_stat'].fillna('NULL')
df1['DP_e_pr'] = df1['DP_e_pr'].fillna('NULL')
df1['DP_e_st'] = df1['DP_e_st'].fillna('NULL')
df1['DP'] = df1['DP'].fillna('NULL')
df1['CAB_d_st'] = df1['CAB_d_st'].fillna('NULL')
df1['CAB_d_pr'] = df1['CAB_d_pr'].fillna('NULL')
df1['port_status'] = df1['port_status'].fillna('NULL')

name1 = df1.columns[17]
name2 = df1.columns[18]
name3 = df1.columns[19]
name4 = df1.columns[20]
name5 = df1.columns[21]
name6 = df1.columns[22]
name7 = df1.columns[38]

df1[name1] = df1['b_line_stat']
df1[name2] = df1['CAB_d_st']
df1[name3] = df1['CAB_d_pr']
df1[name4] = df1['DP_e_st']
df1[name5] = df1['DP_e_pr']
df1[name6] = df1['DP']
df1[name7] = df1['port_status']

frame = frame[frame['caller_id'].isin(df1['caller_id'])]
df1[forPrimary1] = frame['result']

frame1 = frame1[frame1['caller_id'].isin(df1['caller_id'])]
df1[forSecondary1] = frame1['result']

df1[df1['caller_id'].isin(df3['Primary'])]
df1[forPrimary] = df1['caller_id'].fillna('n/a')

df1[df1['adsl'].isin(df2['Adsl'])]
df1[forAdsl] = df1['adsl'].fillna('NULL')

df1[df1['caller_id'].isin(df3['Secondary'])]
df1[forSecondary] = df1['caller_id'].fillna('n/a')

df1['caller_id'] = df1['caller_id'].fillna('NULL')
df1['adsl'] = df1['adsl'].fillna('NULL')

df1.to_excel('dp_util_ANT715-M.xlsx', index=False)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('dp_util_ANT715-M.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Edit: Variables I used in my script to match what is in my question.

Comment: @Parfait I added the expected output and a bit of explanation.

Comment: @Parfait the dashed headers are merged cells. I am having an out of bounds error when I have them, so to perform what I need, I re-created the files without the merged headers first. I am also currently working on how to process the Excel files including the merged headers.

Comment: @Parfait Could you be more specific? Sorry, I didn't quite get what you meant.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your advise. Though, I still look for advise/answer for the objective of my question.